# program in not running completely

Tags: c++, raspberrypi, opencv, ubuntu-mate

I have written a program to count no of cars from the captured video. I have installed opencv and cvblob, raspbian wheezy OS on raspberry pi 2. The problem I am facing is "During run time the program hangs at cvLabel after certain no of iterations.

```
IplImage *labelImg =cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(greyImage), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1); 
unsigned int result = cvLabel(greyImage, labelImg,blobs);
```

But when I run the same program on Virtual Machine in my laptop it will run completely. What might be the reason for this..? Please advice

Comment: Without more specifics, I'd be surprised if anyone can tell you exactly what might be wrong: have you run the program under a suitable memory analysis framework, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)? In any case, it sounds more like a programming question than an Ubuntu question.

Comment: @steeldriver I have installed valgrind but don't know how to use it. Have tried some instruction given on the net but didn't work. Could you please guide me on that..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for my issue. The below changes are required specially for raspberry pi 2(armhf) which avoids the program to run infinite.

https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/issues/detail?id=23

go to /home/pi/cvblob/cvBlob

> In cvLabel.h file

```
const char movesE ... const char movesI ...
```

to

```
const signed char movesE ... const signed char movesI ...
```

> and in cvBlob/cvcontour.cpp , line 84:

change

```
const char cvChainCodeMoves[8][2] = { { 0, -1},
```

to

```
const signed char cvChainCodeMoves[8][2] = { { 0, -1},
```